# Shouldn't emesene themes change the emesene indicator icon?

Tags: icons, ubuntu-10.04

As it stands right now, I can't get the emesene icon in the indicator applet (or notification area, or whatever it's named) to change. No matter what icon theme I choose, even installing new themes, the icon is always the default one. Is that a standard behavior, or am I getting a bug?

I'm running the latest version of emesene from their ppa (1.6-dev), on Lucid Lynx.

EDIT: Turns out it's a known bug for the current ppa version. Kicked in when they switched from tray to indicator applet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the theme... some themes offer more theming than others.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm accepting this aswer as correct so that the question will be marked as answered. But it turns out that it's a bug.